# Prevent Multiple AudioContexts

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I've followed a pattern to attach sound to an object using Webaudio. It works well, however if I generate multiple items on a page and attach this script I get a console.log indicating that I've exceed the maximum number of audioContexts available per page.

My understanding is that the line declares the `audioContext` attaches to the window's AudioContext, not declares a new one. How might I ask the window if it already has an AudioContext and simply add audio nodes to its graph?

```
var that = this
  , audioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

if (!audioContext) {
  console.warn("Web Audio API not supported in this browser.");
  return;
}

this.context = new audioContext();
```

Comment: I think you'll have to check it by yourself. Do you call these lines multiple times ? Is this in a module ? You could try to make the context global.

Comment: It is in a module and this script gets attached to many objects. For less than 4 instances it is fine but more than 4 then it drops voices and logs a message. A global context would be perfect. How might I do that here?

Comment: @Kevin Ennis answer is fine. Otherwise, just move he code creating an AudioContext outside of your module and instead of using `this.context`, just use `context`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand your problem. Is there a reason why you can't just create a single audio context at the top of your script and then have the rest of your code refer to it?

For the sake of providing an answer anyway, you could do something like this:

```
var getContext = function() {
  var ac = null;
  if ( !window.AudioContext && !window.webkitAudioContext ) {
    console.warn('Web Audio API not supported in this browser');
  } else {
    ac = new ( window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext )();
  }
  return function() {
    return ac;
  };
}();
```

Then, every time you need a context, you just call this function:

```
var ctx = getContext(),
  osc = ctx.createOscillator();
osc.connect(ctx.destination);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However I don't fully understand why. Can you point me to keywords or concepts as to why this works?

Comment: The basic idea is that it uses a closure. Essentially, the outer function executes immediately (notice those parenthesis at very the end? those invoke it) and creates an audio context for you. It also returns a new function that does nothing but return the audio context. So, you're basically saying "`getContext` is equal to the result of calling this outer function". And since the return value of the outer function is yet another function, that's what you get. Closures can be a bit tough to wrap your mind around at first (they were for me) -- but a bit of googling should get you on track.